# PHP: Error on Update statement with subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, subquery

I have a page that updates the data of a specific user. The user has position, which is a foreign key. The query update (below) works fine without the position, but with the position I get the following error.

**Query :**

```
 $queryUpdate = "UPDATE visitorsystem.employee SET idNumber = '$idNumber', name = '$name',
                            surname = '$surname',
                            position = 'SELECT positionid FROM visitorsystem.position WHERE positionName LIKE '%$position%'',
                            email = '$email'
                            WHERE employeeid = '$empId'";

                            $resultUpdate = mysqli_query($connection,$queryUpdate)
                                or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
```

> Error in query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'SELECT positionid FROM visitorsystem.position WHERE
>   positionName LIKE '%Informat' at line 3

I have tried to work my way around by using inner join as I have seen some solutions given here on stack but nothing has worked. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Your subquery shouldn't be between quotes, but between parentheses

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subqueries go within regular parens, not quotes, so in a general sense:

```
SELECT x FROM y WHERE z IN (SELECT z FROM a)
```

Single and double quotes (by default) are *only* for string values.

Comment: I have tried in parenthesis as well but unfortunately it still won't work

Comment: "Won't work" is not a useful diagnostic. You may have other problems. Check your error log for details. Get *something* we can use to help you.

Comment: I have tried placing the whole subquery in parentheses multiple times and a parse error was given. I closed my browser and applied the change again, somehow it made a difference and worked this time. Pretty confusing .. Thanks for the help :) !  I will also take note on the security issues, Thanks for pointing it out